# How to Update CSS and Variable Using GSAP Tween

Tags: javascript, gsap

Consider the following code (not tested, just an example):

```
const item = document.getElementById('test');

let value = 0;
let finalValue = 100;

TweenMax.fromTo(
    item,
    .2,
    { '--some-var': value },
    {
        '--some-var': finalValue
        onComplete: () => {
            value = finalValue;
        }
    }
);
```

The above code uses TweenMax (although TweenLite would be preferred if it supports what I need...) to update the `--some-var` CSS property of `item`. At the moment, I am using `onComplete` to update `value` to the `finalValue` of the animation, however, I would ideally like to do this at the same time as the tween.

In other words, I would like the Tween to update the following two values as it runs:

- `--some-var` of `item`
- `value`

I am aware that I can pass an `array` to target, but from what I understand, that will set the `value` variable to an object like so `{ '--some-var': XXX }` instead of just `XXX`.

Is there a way to update two objects that have different structures? i.e. One is a DOM node (CSS update), and one is a simple variable...

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible. In fact, Carl made a [quick tip on how to do so](https://greensock.com/css-variables). Just make sure you are animating the actual *variable*, not the element where it is called.

If you want more help in your case, please provide a minimal example of the code that reproduces your error.